# table architecture,what is the best practice?

Tags: sql

i know this is a strange question !
i need to create a table called "Smartphone".
the question is about number of columns.

do i must to create every column for every characteristic ?

(Model
Band
SIM
Telephone operator
Shell material
Operating System
CPU
GPU
ROM
RAM
Storage expansion
Size
Type
Resolution
Ringtones
Audio
Video
Image
E-book
FM Radio 
Earphones
Data transfer
Internet
Camera
Battery
Languages
Posts
Entry
TV
GPS
JAVA
WIFI
Bluetooth
Gravity Sensor
Multi-Touch
Dimensions
Weight
Standby time
Size
Weight
Accessories
)

or i just need to create the general characteristics and in the last. i create an column called “moreinformations” wish i put all information’s ...

cause i need to show all this information's and fliter by specific characteristics

what is the best practice ?

Comment: Depends. If some of these dimensions are related, you can create a separate table for them, and create a primary key to represent each unique combination. Then, just include that as a foreign key in your main table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put all available MODEL BANDS, SIM, OPERATORS, SHELL MATERIAL, etc, so that every value which repeats and is not integer, into separated tables and then use foreign key. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE systems
(
    ID int not null primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    -- other parameters
)
```

Other values, like bluetooth, wi-fi, would be boolean if the only states are exists or not exists, or numeric if there could be more values.

If there could be more bands or other things, I would create another table BAND LINKS, which links smartphones and bands, example band1 has ID=1, band2 had ID=2, and smartphone1 has ID=1, then I would insert into table BAND LINKS values (1,1) and (1,2) which means that 1 and 2 band is connected to ID=1 smartphone. Of course I would add procedures to improve performance.

Comment: thank you alot! i alredy put 2 tables (brand,os) wich i link them with table (smartphone) ,the question is if i put all availables in a single table (smartphone) it will be Ok ? cause i don't get ur idea about create other table wish grouped by typeof variable!